# Can't link GLFW3: undefined references

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, undefined-reference, glfw

I realize something similar has been asked before ([glfw3 compiling undefined references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362063/glfw3-compiling-undefined-references)), but I still can't get it to work unfortunately. Any help is welcome!

Below is the compiler output when running *make*:

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors  -I/usr/local/include  -c -o Main.o Main.cpp
>
> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors  -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib  -lglfw3  -lGL   Main.o -o modernogl
>
> Main.o: In function `main':
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
>
> Main.cpp:(.text+0x97): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> make: *** [modernogl] Error 1

Here is what the include and lib directories have inside them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUIu8.png

Below is the source (there shouldn't be any problem with it though...):

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return 1;
    }

    GLFWwindow* window {glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Modern OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr)};
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
- Erik

Answer (score 3):

I only had the static version of the library "libglfw3.a", I needed the shared version of it "libglfw.so". Make sure to build GLFW3 with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON!

Comment: Just to make it clear: `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON .`