# Unresolved external symbol when I add glfw3.lib to compiler argument

Tags: linker, linker-errors, lnk2019

I have written a little batch file to compile a project from emacs and when I added a `glfw3.lib` to compiler argument I started to get this error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glfwInit referenced in function WinMain.

So I created a project in Visual Studio 2012, added SAME libs and SAME includes, it magically compiled. What am I doing wrong?

This is my `build.bat` file:

```
@echo off

mkdir ..\Build
pushd ..\Build
cl -Zi ..\source\win32main.cpp -I..\includes user32.lib gdi32.lib opengl32.lib ..\libs\glew32.lib ..\libs\glfw3.lib
popd
```

Main file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>

int CALLBACK
WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance,
    HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
    LPSTR CommandLine,
    int ShowCode)
{
    glfwInit(); // Here is the error, but i don't get why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to change the order of *.lib in your build.bat file, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19362063/992406

Comment: No, still the same error. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm using Microsoft's compiler v17.0 and Linker v11.0.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I added this flag to linker `-nodefaultlib:libcmt.lib`